# nmap not showing hostname after changing it in /etc/hostname

Tags: networking

When I run `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` I get (among other things)

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.198
Host is up (0.17s latency).
MAC Address: 56:31:C4:A0:1B:3E (Unknown)
```

which I know is referring to the Raspberry Pi device I'm interested in, because I've verified the IP address on the device with `hostname -I`.

Somwehere among those lines `raspberrypi` was showing up before. But ever since I changed my hostname by tweaking `/etc/hostname` it's not showing me the hostname when I run `nmap`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This depends more on the machine you are running nmap from.  The problem may be that there are restrictions on what hostnames are valid for mDNS; the linux implementation doesn't enforce them but (eg) Windows does, so if you are looking from a window environment it will ignore "illegal" hostnames.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for jumping in. I'm calling `nmap` from ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @goldilocks your comment prompted me to try changing the hostname from `rpi4-proto` to `rpi4proto` and now I get `Rasberry Pi Trading` in place of `Unknown`. I'd still like to see the hostname somehow. I would expect to see it inline just before the IP address right?

Comment: *"now I get Rasberry Pi Trading in place of Unknown"* -> This has nothing to do with the hostname; it's a MAC address lookup -- which it is a bit odd the MAC address in your question perhaps *isn't* a Pi: [here's a lookup of that OUI](https://aruljohn.com/mac/5631C4) (unknown).  Now here's [one with the OUI from a Pi 4 wifi interface](https://aruljohn.com/mac/DCA632) (Raspberry Pi Trading).  That's not necessarily definitive, but you should check the MAC address from the Pi with `ip link`.